# Flex 4.5.1 - Database access problem on mobile simulator

Tags: database, sqlite, mobile, flex4.5

I am trying to connect to a SQLite database that's located in the assets folder of a project.
I wrote up a class, here is the part that is throwing an error:

```
public class Database
{
    private var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;

    public function connect(db:String):Object
    {
        var response:Object={status:false,message:''};
        try
        {
            var dbFile:File=File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(db);
            sqlConnection.open(dbFile);
            response.status=true;
            response.message='';
        }
        catch(error:SQLError)
        {
            response.status=false
            response.message=error.message;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I call that class in an MXML view component on the `creationComplete` handler:

```
private function init():void
{
    var db:Database=new Database();
    var connectResponse:Object=db.connect('assets/data.db');
    if(connectResponse.status)
    {
        //getData() runs a simple select query and returns an array
        acData=new ArrayCollection(db.getData());
    }
    else
    {
        //If the status is false I show a label control for debugging
        labelError.text=connectResponse.message;
        labelError.includeInLayout=true;
        labelError.visible=true;
    }

    list.dataProvider=acData;
}
```

The error I get is something along the lines: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`.

Comment: what line is throwing the TypeError?

Comment: Line 22, which is `sqlConnection.open(dbFile);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to instantiate your sqlConnection before you use it:

```
sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
sqlConnection.open(dbFile);
```

Comment: Haha, I can't belive I missed that. I've been trying to figure it out for almost 2 days now... Thank you, 6.